# Question About Equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cauchy-sequences

I am wondering if the following statement is true, and if not, why not?

If $l-\epsilon < a_n < l + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a_n = l$.

This is in the context of Cauchy Sequences. I had learned of the Squeeze Theorem in the past in calculus (although never a proof for it), and I presumed that the above statement would be true due to the squeeze theorem. But now with Cauchy Sequences, things seem to get a little more dicey, since we're dealing with epsilon neighborhoods. Can I not just treat $a_n$ as another variable like $l$? And if so, why not? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I am confused about what tools you are permitting yourself to use in answering this question you have.  If you are familiar with the squeeze theorem, how does it fail to address this problem?  or are you disallowing the use of the squeeze theorem for some reason?  In what context are you asking this question---you mention topology; what definitions have you learned recently which might be relevant?

Comment: Your inequlity seems to refer to a number called $a_n$ which is not changing as $\epsilon$ is taken arbitrarily small and positive. So it is the same as if you replaced $a_n$ with a letter like $c,$ which would have the advantage of not seeming to refer to a sequence of values but to a single value. This other version with $c$ in it is true, but if you have $a_n$ in there it is a misleading inequality, in my opinion.

Comment: Moreover, is this the entire question?  (As coffeemath pointed out while I was typing,) the term in the middle is indexed by $n$.  What does this mean?  Where does this come from?  Since you mention equivalences, I wonder if you are, perhaps, starting to study Cauchy sequences?  Again, it would help to know the context in which this question is being asked.

Comment: My apologies everyone! I edited the question to give more detail and context now.

Comment: To answer the question literally: yes. In general, if $a< b+\epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$, then $a\le b$. One can prove that by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is true. More generally, the following two results hold:

1. If $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a\le b$.
2. If $a > c - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a \ge c$.

In fact, (2) follows from (1), since $a > c -\epsilon$ if and only if $c < a + \epsilon$. So, it is enough to prove (1).

*Proof.* Suppose $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. We want to show that $a \le b$. For a contradiction, assume $a > b$, i.e. $m: =a- b > 0$. As $m > \frac{m}{2}$, $a > b + \frac{m}{2}$. But this contradicts the hypothesis, $a < b + \frac{m}{2}$. Therefore, $a \le b$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

From (1) and (2) it is clear that
$$l - \epsilon < a_n < l + \epsilon\, \,\text{  for all }\epsilon > 0 \implies a_n = l$$

Comment: This is great, thank you!